# KeyCloak REST API: how to map a Role with a Group

Tags: keycloak

I am using KeyCloak REST APIs and created a GROUP and a ROLE. Using REST API how to assign the ROLE to the Group?
Here is the relevant APIs -
[KeyClaok API Guide](https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/d/red-hat-single-sign-on/version-7.0.0/restapi/#_add_realm_level_role_mappings_to_the_user)

```
POST /admin/realms/{realm}/groups/{id}/role-mappings/realm
```

So question is how to use this API? Should I at first create the ROLE or this API itself will create the ROLE and do the mapping?

I tried in both the ways -

1. Create the ROLE by POST, retrieve the RoleId from the response and send another POST to `/admin/realms/{realm}/groups/{id}/role-mappings/realm` by re-sending the same `RoleRepresentation` object with the created Id. Also I passed the `GroupId` with whom I want to map the Role. But I am getting error.
2. In this case I didn't create the Role at the very beginning, but sent the `RoleRepresentation` object in the `/admin/realms/{realm}/groups/{id}/role-mappings/realm` API call. Again I am getting error.

The API guide is not clear on how to map the Group with the Role.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request is good. For example I have this one:

```
http://localhost:5440/auth/admin/realms/{yourRealm}/groups/8129e7ed-db5f-423b-91f5-779b9d448d3b/role-mappings/realm
```

But you have to create the role first and send this `RoleRepresentation` in your `BodyParameter`. There is an array of `RoleRepresentation`.

For example my array of `RoleRepresentation` with one role:

```
[{"id":"16f77b0f-a03e-4995-a09f-dc02a0ee3f03","name":"rolle2","scopeParamRequired":false,"composite":false,"clientRole":false,"containerId":"yourRealm"}]
```

Comment: Hi @Apetrei Ionut, thanks a ton! The array is the key point! I missed it. I was just sending the Role without creating an array of Roles (with only one element). Now the code is working fine. Thanks again. Have a nice day.

Comment: What if I want to assign a role created in a client not in a realm

Comment: To add on to this: it seems that both the 'id and 'name' together are sufficient. For some reason, 'id' alone is not enough.